# Energy in Capacitor

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

Really struggling to get a script for the energy in a capacitor.

Using the formula:

```
v(t) = (1/c)*int(i(t)) dt
```

The script need to be able to accept arrays i.e.

```
t = 0,1,2,3,4
i = 2,3,5,5,8
```

Where **C** is a fixed value
for example, I'm sure this is very easy for someone experienced in coding. But personally I’m having a nightmare with it!

Comment: First, int() might not be doing what you expect if you do not have the symbolic math toolbox. Second, if you post some code, it will be easier to make a specific response. Third, the variation of current (i) over time is quite large to get good numerical integration. You might want to break time up into many smaller intervals and make dt smaller.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the running integral using [`cumtrapz`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/cumtrapz.html):

```
t = [0,1,2,3,4];
i = [2,3,5,5,8];
C = 1; %// example data

v = 1/C * cumtrapz(t,i);
```